# php mailer is not working hotmail

Tags: php, email

```
<?php


$to = 'xyz@hotmail.com';

$subject = 'the subject';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers = 'From: acb@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: acb@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$message = 'hi hello';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo 'mail sent';


?>
```

As I am sending mail using above code .. it is working fine ..
but mails are not going to hot mail...
can anyone help me in this please

Comment: Hotmail doesn't like the mail() function. Try sending mails through a valid SMTP account.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a plethora of things. One of the more common ones is that you are telling them you are sending mail from a gmail account but are not actually connecting to them from a gmail server.

If you could provide us with more information (specifically, lines concerning delivery from your mail.log) we could help better but most likely it is either that you aren't allowed to send mail for gmail and/or that your server is marked as "bad" by hotmail.

Answer (score 0):

The hotmail spam filter stopped it, and with good reason. Advise i can give you:

Send it to yourself, and see the raw message. You may find that the `From:` address has changed and differs form the `Reply-To:`. To avoid that, send the email via `SMTP` instead.

If the domain you send from has a SPF DNS record, that may help. Spam filters use this to look up the authenticity of emails that claim to come from a certain domain.

This is why the `@gmail.com` address you used is certainly not going to pass through..